# Unsupported Media when trying to create new "put" file in crowdstrike API using php curl

Tags: php, curl

This is the error returned when I'm trying to create a 'put' file in crowdstrike api using php curl.

```
 "errors": [
  {
   "code": 415,
   "message": "415: Unsupported Media Type\n\nAvailable representations: "
  }
 ]
```

And here is the curl that I'm using. The same curl script will work only if I remove the

`'file '=> new CURLFILE('/C:/test_file.jpg')` in the post fields array.

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    
    $authorization = 'authorization: Bearer '.trim($token);
    $header = [
    // 'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
    $authorization
    ];
    
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.us-2.crowdstrike.com/real-time-response/entities/put-files/v1',
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('name' => 'test_file.jpg','description' => 'testing','content' => 'content','file '=> new CURLFILE('/C:/test_file.jpg')),
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header
    ));
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
```

**EDIT:**
[image]

Comment: `/C:/test_file.jpg` - that leading slash there makes no sense at all.

Comment: @CBroe Actually that curl script is from postman that is also working. Don't know why its not working when I run it on my php.

Comment: I don't see how that path can make any sense. The `:` is not allowed in folder names on Windows, so the only way `C:` would make sense, is as a drive letter - but to have that meaning, it needs to be at the very start of the path, not after a slash. (Or is there anything special about your setup, that we don't know about? Different OS? Drives mounted somehow, so that that path _could_ make sense?)

Comment: I removed the leading slash and it runs without errors. It saves the name, description and content but the file seems to be corrupted. Its less than 10kb when its originally 3MB.

Comment: Do you have any documentation for this API endpoint? _"Its less than 10kb when its originally 3MB"_ - unlikely, that cURL would mess up reading and sending the file data. What _do_ those 10kb of data actually contain, when you go check the database?

Comment: Updated my question with the API docs. Its literally a 3MB image file the is uploaded.

Comment: Again: What do those 10kb of data actually contain, when you go check the database?

Comment: When I tried to open the image in notepad it contains `content` string. Its supposed to be binary right?

Comment: Yes, image data is usually binary (if we are not talking SVG.) _"it contains `content` string"_ - what, the literal _text_ `content`? That alone would hardly be 10KB.

Comment: Oh sorry my bad, its 7 bytes. Yes its a text `content`. Maybe its from the other `content` key that has the same value content.

Comment: Yes, must be from that. Why are you sending that in the first place, I don't see that in your screenshot above? (My _guess_ would be that this API lets you perform either a _real_ HTTP file upload - or that you can also pass the file content separately, using that `content` option. In that case, you'd be doing a mixture of both right now, and that probably doesn't make much sense.)

Comment: That content is not actually at the docs but it returns `content is required` error when its not included XD. Also tried to convert content to file in postman but still return `content is required`

Answer (score 0):

I somehow make it work. First I think the crowdstrike API docs are incorrect since the key `content` is required but not in the docs. Also the key `file` is not required contrary to the docs. So Here's the updated curl script.

```
$curl = curl_init();

$authorization = 'authorization: Bearer '.trim($token);
$header = [
// 'Content-Type: application/json',
'Content-Type: multipart/form-data',
$authorization
];

$uploadfile = file_get_contents('C:/test_file.jpg');

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.us-2.crowdstrike.com/real-time-response/entities/put-files/v1',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('name' => 'test_file.jpg','description' => 'testing','content' => $uploadfile),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
```